# libVLC|make: undefined reference to `libvlc_new'

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, libvlc

For a small project, I decided to use `libvlc` hence  C/C++.

Using different references I somehow installed opencv and libvlc libraries and also wrote the following CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/platform
        )

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(LIBVLC REQUIRED)



file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
        )
add_executable(untitled1 ${SOURCE_FILES})

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "2.8.11")
    # Add OpenCV headers location to your include paths
    include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()


include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${LIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LIBVLC_LIBRARIES} )



target_link_libraries( untitled1 ${LIBS})
```

But when I do, `cmake` and then `make` I get the following error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled1
CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/VLCReader.cpp.o: In function `VLCReader::VLCReader(char*)':
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:17: undefined reference to `libvlc_new'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:18: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_new'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:21: undefined reference to `libvlc_video_set_callbacks'
CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/VLCReader.cpp.o: In function `VLCReader::~VLCReader()':
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:26: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_stop'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:27: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_release'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:28: undefined reference to `libvlc_release'
CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/VLCReader.cpp.o: In function `VLCReader::start(int, int)':
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:33: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_pause'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:34: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_new_location'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:35: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_set_media'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:36: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_release'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:38: undefined reference to `libvlc_video_set_format'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:39: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_play'
CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/VLCReader.cpp.o: In function `VLCReader::pause(bool)':
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:45: undefined reference to `libvlc_media_player_set_pause'
CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/VLCReader.cpp.o: In function `VLCReader::updataSize()':
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:51: undefined reference to `libvlc_video_get_width'
/home/ravinder/CLionProjects/untitled1/VLCReader.cpp:52: undefined reference to `libvlc_video_get_height'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/build.make:166: recipe for target 'untitled1' failed
```

Please help me in going ahead. I am really new to C/C++ cmake based world.

Comment: The linker cannot find several "libvlc" definitions, which suggests that you are missing these libraries. Can you verify that the `LIBVLC_LIBRARIES` CMake variable is populated with valid libraries? You can use the CMake `message` command as you did for the OpenCV variables.

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlcpp this should help

Comment: Under one of directories which you assign to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable you have `FindLIBVLC.cmake` script, which is actually executed during processing the call to `find_package(LIBVLC)`. Read documentation at the top of that script, and find out which **actual** variables it sets for use them in your project. Most likely, variable `LIBVLC_LIBRARIES`, which you use in your code, is not set by this script at all.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks sir for pinting I same thing :) It's singular variable set by FindLIBVLC while I was using plural one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tsyvarev and other people who pinted me in right direction.

My mistake in the CMake file is that I am using wrong variable names or say usng variables whihc are not defined.

`LIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIRS` to `LIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIR`

`LIBVLC_LIBRARIES` to `LIBVLC_LIBRARY`

Thanks all!